# My advisor submitted a paper with my work without including me as an author

Tags: journals, advisor, ethics, authorship

As you might see from my history I don't have a good relationship with my advisor. Recently we wrote a journal paper together based on my thesis. I wrote the introduction, analysis and the description of the app we had developed for our research. In crude terms, I wrote 15 pages of the 23 page journal paper. My advisor told me that our draft was submitted to this journal three weeks ago, yet I never received any notification from the journal that I was listed as author or co-author.

I went into the help section of the journal to figure if they do send emails to every author and it seems you do need an email to register as co-author. Confirmation [here](http://journalauthors.tandf.co.uk/pdfs/SubmitGuide_S1M_1.pdf).

According to the guidelines, if the co-author is not registered with the journal, their email should be provided. Its quite obvious I should have received an confirmation email and my advisor only has my .edu email so there is no way another email address could have been used. I have written a journal paper to IEEE as co-author before and I had received an confirmatory email saying I was listed as co-author.  I am afraid of confronting my advisor about this as I need co-operation to graduate and in my thesis defense, but I was curious to know if I will get an email if I am listed as co-author? More importantly, should I be listed as author or co-author in this case, when the work is based on my thesis and I wrote most of the paper?

I called the 1-800 number and when I told them the submitter's last name (my advisor) and the paper title, they confirmed that my advisor was listed as sole author. They told me that they had to un-submit and resubmit the journal paper to add me as co-author and they gave me contact of a University professor for further inquiries. I have all the email proof of my work (for instance emails where my advisor asks me to write intro and I would reply with the intro text attached and so on). I am seriously upset right now. I have my thesis defense in December and I fear that if I confront my advisor, things will screw up. Can you  please advise on what I should do right now?

PS:  I was told that I am listed in Acknowledgement section in the end, which is completely unfair. The Deciding officer (it seems he is the final authority in these cases and RIO reports to him) at my University is the vice president, who was my advisor's PhD Advisor half a decade ago. They are both from same city of a foreign country and are close family friends. Rumor has it that the Vice President rejected multiple highly qualified candidates to get my advisor for Asst. Prof. Position.  All my friends are asking me to drop it because I don't have many bullets to go after them, but they can completely screw me up or set me up for something if I go against "one of their own". I am still evaluating what to do.

PPS: Thank you for all your advice. Even though I don't know any of you personally, you were very kind in giving me your time and advice. I cannot thank you all enough. I spoke with a full professor in another deptartment in Engineering. He asked me to stay put till December until the paper is published. He was of opinion that the University is a big cesspool and they only way to clean it is to "get the people" who are doing this publicly and shame them. I do not know if I am being used as pawn right now in University politics or what I should do. I  spoke with other people too and all they said was "Is not getting an authorship on journal worth more than not earning the degree". It seems sole authorship does carry extra weight age in front of tenure committee. The whole situation has completely shattered my faith in academics, and the fact that I am part of a state university makes this even more depressing. By the way, one of the two editors of this journal was on advisor's PhD committee. So many people have advised me not to contact any of them. In academia everybody seems to know everybody, in fact it seems more like a cult. I am just doing a Masters now, I always had plans to do PhD and explore my curiosities and see what I can achieve with perseverance, hard work and to test my mental capabilities to their limit, but I am done. I quit. I never felt so depressed for a very long time. Academia these days seems to run by industry practitioners who had previous experience at corporate politics and are good at it or by businessman who wear good clothes, have good people skills and just show off while delegating all the work to GRAs and underlings, and that's not what I am and will never be.

Comment: Have you discussed the authorship issue with your advisor at all?  (I mean earlier, not in response to this.)  Or has it ever been explicitly mentioned in e-mail?  Even "I've submitted our article to the journal" makes it sound like joint work, while "I've submitted the article on X" leaves it ambiguous.  If your advisor has clearly talked about it as a joint paper, then that establishes something.  If it's always been talked about ambiguously or as your advisor's paper, then you're in a tougher situation (although what you've described certainly makes it sound like you should be a coauthor).

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician well we always talked about it as our paper as it was based on my thesis. Basically the journal lifts up lit review and technical description from my thesis. In fact I feel I should be author instead of co author based on volume of pages I have written.

Comment: Tell her that you haven't gotten any e-mail, suspecting that the journal might have messed up your e-mail address, you called and sadly found out that THEY missed you in the process. Ask her if "we should retract." Give her one last way out. If she has half a brain or if it's an honest mistake, she will retract. If she waves hands or tries to hula dance away from you, then come back here and we may be able to give you some better suggestion, depending on how much you are willing to pay the reaper when these all are over.

Comment: I just went through some of your older questions, and it seems that your supervisor is a seriously nasty piece of work. Please, for the love of science, once you've safely graduated, go to your university's Ombudsman with all the grievances you've collected. Assuming what you say is all true, people like this are what destroy our profession, and the lives of countless others. I completely understand if, after you graduate, you want to forget this thing as quickly as possible, but please keep in mind that if you don't do anything, there will be others.

Comment: I would say — if there’s *anyone* suitable at your university (faculty member, ombudsman, ethics council…) that you can trust a bit, don’t wait until you’ve graduated to raise this issue!  Write to the person and say something like: “I have an ethical concern I would be grateful for help with; can I ask your advice in confidentiality?”  Leave details until later; hopefully they can help/support you, and worst-case scenario, you just go back to waiting.  Unless your whole university is quite corrupt, they’ll be very unlikely to betray the confidentiality once they have offered it in writing.

Comment: keep calm and wait till December.

Comment: _The Deciding officer (it seems he is final authority in these cases..._ — Nope.  The final authority on the authorship of a journal paper is **the journal editor**.

Comment: Honestly, in your shoes, I would be tempted just leave, after writing an open letter to both the president of the university and the editors of the journal, with links to a public web page that includes a complete data and email trail.  I would have absolutely no trust that my advisor would actually sign off on my thesis and let me graduate, or would work on my behalf to help me find a job, so what would I stand to lose?  This level of unethical behavior is not just an embarrassment to your advisor, but to your department, your university, and your chosen field of research.

Comment: But ***DO NOT*** actually write a public-shaming letter like that without soliciting the (confidential) advice and (anonymous) help of a trusted senior colleague, exactly as @PLL suggests.

Comment: I would suggest blocking that publication process by reporting to the editor first.

Comment: Definitely let the editor know!  As a journal editor, I would much rather learn about a situation like this before the paper was published than after.  You can ask them to keep it confidential for a while so you can investigate how to handle it.  There's no guarantee that they will do so, but it seems like a reasonable request and I would certainly agree.

Comment: Firstly, sorry to hear the sad updates. Contacting journal editor wouldn't guarantee anything because your advisor can submit somewhere else as sole author again. (And this is likely considering his/her dark personality)

Also, maybe you shouldnt quit the idea of doing ph.d.

Comment: Very sorry to hear about your final update. These bad experiences that you had are definitely not the academia I know. From my personal experience this type of behavior is extremely rare and most academics would find it disgusting. Don't lose faith in academia.

Comment: I just read your story.  While I would say it is quite rare in academia, it is definitely not unknown.  I do know of universities of which, at least in part, are huge cesspools.  I know you might be very angry.  But I would assess what you are going to do in terms of your self-interest.  If you confront the situation, or go public, you may face a severe backlash.  One option is to cut your losses and move on.  I'm not saying that is what you should do.  But I am saying that is an option worth great consideration.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith There is not a day that goes by away without me getting by angry by the stuff i have to deal with. I am just bottling up all my emotions and its screwing up with me and affecting me in other things.My advisor doesnt know that i know about these things.My lab is not able to find a good programmer to do development. My project has brought 3 more new projects from industry and there are not able to find quality developers to do the work for them.They are persuading me now to stay back for one more sem since according to them "i am the best developer in Dept. right now".

Comment: @james234 If I were you, I would put your emotional well-being first.  Put the needs of the department last.  You are in a difficult place, because if you expose the situation, you could get badly hurt.  Finally, I found that these kinds of difficulties brought me to God.  I don't want to shove religion down your throat, but if you are interested you can follow my biography to my web-page, and finally to my personal experiences.

Comment: Also, compare your situation with someone who is in an abusive relationship.  You keep hoping that things could get better, but they don't.  I know you haven't yet confronted your adviser.  But the power inequity is so great.  If you knew he/she would react well, it would be OK.  Is there someone else who knows your adviser well?  Maybe they would know.  But your adviser does have a lot of power to mess up your life in terms of letters of recommendation, etc.  And there do exist people who are really mean.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Rot lies much deeper here. I came to know last week that a phd student is funded from my project and he gets paid more than me.But on proposal it was listed that i will be only RA working on it . My Lab brought Iphones and ipads from research funds of my project and have passed it on as "usability evaluation of mobile phones" and are using them for personal pleasure in their homes with their kids. My thesis defense is this month end. I am planning to complete it and just go public with everything and i will face  consequences that may result because of it.

Comment: @james234 It is laudable what you want to do.  But count the cost before you start.  It is possible that people won't want to listen.  I have done some of this exposing myself http://www.columbiatribune.com/commentary/op-ed/mu-s-administrative-culture-is-toxic/article_11f434de-15ee-5e75-9674-e26a237e9c3a.html and it was never quite as cathartic or effective as I hoped for.  What you are wanting to do is noble.  But be prepared for disappointments.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Thankyou ,that was an depressing but interesting read.I will wait for my defense and then   let her know that i knew everything all along. Although its useless at this point ,i will tell her that i acted in good faith all along but she took advantage of it and betrayed the trust. Although i doubt she has any conscience ,i will let everybody in my department know about it discreetly through my friends and other GRAs.Even though i may not be able to do anything,i can let everybody know what happened so that they remember this when her tenure comes up.

Comment: @james234 I read the whole story and I really would like to hear updates from you. I think I am facing somehow similar dilemma. I wrote an entire conference paper (everything with implementation) and the supervisor told me he wants to put his name first. I had bad relationship with him for long time and now I am awaiting my thesis defence. I could not stop him. But I feel so angry inside and considering to quit academia because of that. It is unbearably unfair

Comment: @hawk You just have to think it is bad luck and move on. These people are very well connected (My advisor knows provost people in univ. admin personally).You have to believe in karma and hope they don't get ahead in career.I think these people look for students who they know won't go against them and then do their thing.They don't do like this with everybody.It is just heartbreaking to invest so much in a lab and then suddenly realize you were just a fool all these days to trust them and believe them. Just move on ,but if you want to fight make sure you have all the paper trail first

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It is an *unambiguous violation of ethics* for a collaborator to be dropped from the list of authors.

If you wrote a significant contribution to the paper, **you are in the right.** Your supervisor has no ground to stand on. You should *ask* your supervisor (don't accuse!) if he/she has included you as a co-author. If a mistake has been made, the sooner it's fixed the better. You could also have a good claim to first authorship, though that is something to decide between authors.

> Edit: a little humour - full credit goes to [Nik Papageorgiou / The Upturned Microscope](http://upmic.wordpress.com).

[image]

Comment: Moriarty as in... Sixtysymbols?

Comment: Nope, it's not my real name.

Answer (score 18):

There may be nothing to worry about.  In ScholarOne (the web submission system being used), the submitter is supposed to enter contact information for all the authors, but an impatient submitter might skip that.  As long as you are listed as an author on the paper itself, I'd bet the web submission stuff can be fixed after the fact (it might annoy people, but it's unlikely to derail publication).  Probably the person you called at the publisher just checked the ScholarOne metadata without examining the submitted PDF, in which case you don't know for sure whether it lists you.

Instead of provoking an angry confrontation, I'd focus on first figuring out whether you and your advisor are in agreement on authorship.  I'll assume you have not explicitly discussed this question, since if you had, then you should have ended up with agreement one way or the other, or at least known you disagreed.

As a first step, you could bring up the question.  For example, you could write "I realized recently that we never explicitly discussed authorship of our paper.  I've envisioned myself as first author and you as the senior author, since I wrote much of the paper and it is based on my thesis work.  However, I should have discussed this with you before submission.  What's your take on the author ordering, and how did you handle it in the submission?"

Then you can decide what to do based on her response.  If she explicitly says you're an author, then I'd trust her on this.  You could still discuss author ordering, based on the conventions in your field.

If your advisor says she doesn't think you should be an author at all, then you'll have to discuss this issue.  It would be counterproductive to accuse her of dishonesty or of trying to steal your work.  Instead, you should just try to make the case that your contributions justify coauthorship.  You could refer to guidelines for this journal or for your field in general to help you argue.

Comment: i will call them again tmrw at toll free and ask them to look into journal draft itself if they can .Otherwise they gave me details of a prof. they asked me to contact. I will ask them for details and will ask to them to keep everything confidential.

Comment: _If your advisor says she doesn't think you should be an author at all, then you'll have to discuss this issue._ — But **first** collect a _complete_ trail of your work and email exchanges with your advisor, and discuss the situation—calmly, professionally, and without being accusatory—with an informed third party, like your department chair or ombudsman.  An advisor publishing their student's graduate thesis work without the student's name is grossly unethical, but just being _right_ won't necessarily help you.  **Be prepared to burn all bridges with your advisor.**

Comment: Not just unethical, but also counterproductive. At the advisor stage, the main challenge is showing that you can advise PhD students who produce publishable work. If you "steal" publications from them you are just stealing from your own future career.

Answer (score 4):

> I am seriously upset right now. I have my thesis defense in December and I fear that if I confront my advisor, she will screw me up.

Simply as a matter of self-interest, your adviser probably doesn't want you to fail your defense. The work is being published in a journal, and at least one of the names on the paper is hers. If it's then being judged as academically inadequate for a PhD, that reflects badly on her.

Also, if she's really as bad as she sounds, she'll have a reputation at your school, and many of the people on your committee will realize that.

A more realistic concern is that this is also the time when you're going to be applying for your first job, and she may not give you a good recommendation. E.g., if you're applying for a postdoc at another university, people there probably don't know her personally and don't understand your situation. Once you get past the hurdle of getting that first job, you no longer have to depend on your adviser for a recommendation. One option to consider would be to get that job lined up before starting a big row over authorship of this paper.

Comment: I actually have job lined up in a research division of an  corp in which my advisor had no hand. So i am not concerned abt reco letter.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, web submission software *can* send authorship confirmation emails to all co-authors, but not all journal publishers actually configure it to do so. I can confirm that at least one journal by Taylor & Francis does not send confirmation emails to people other than the corresponding author.

Comment: please see my edit.