# How to handle a lack of authorship even though you deserved it?

Tags: publications, advisor, authorship, plagiarism

In Summer 2020, I worked on a research team with 2 colleagues and a supervisor on a ML paper. We (myself and my 2 colleagues) heavily built on some work that the supervisor did in the past to come up with a new channel adaptation approach for common CNN models. Due to our significant work done, we expected to be notable authors on the paper.

In September 2020, we took a step back from working on the paper due to school work. There were some other students who were able to help at the time of publishing in November 2020. Unfairly, we got last authors on a paper that was built on our approaches.

We tried to get the paper published to CVPR (a notable computer vision conference), but had some problems that unfortunately got it rejected.

However, next year, the supervisor (without telling us) was able to get a new paper republished in another notable ML conference. Initially, we thought the paper was quite different. But, it turns out that the conference paper had our approaches almost to a T. Furthermore, we got no author credit, even though graphs and algorithms from our work clearly made it.

As an **undergrad**, I was really hoping to get a published paper on my record, and I put the commensurate work for that during the research term. Instead, we got no author credit to the final conference paper, and our work was clearly taken from the previous paper, but not properly credited.

I am wondering about complaining to university authorities, but I am not 100% sure I want to start a mess for a paper I don't think I could get authorship to. That being said, it would be a huge help to get a paper authorship for grad school apps.

If any guidance could be provided as to what I could do for the authorship, or whether I should complain, it would be greatly appreciated.

TLDR: Supervisor published a paper with the work of myself and my colleagues, but didn't credit us at all. What should I do?

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/126485/my-supervisor-published-our-work-without-informing-us-can-we-retract-the-paper

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/140316/supervisor-published-my-thesis-figures-without-including-me-as-an-author

Comment: Definitely, tremendously helpful. I think the 3 questions above cover the gist of what I was looking for. Thank you!