# My previous PI used my data in an article that was published in a high profile journal. My name is nowhere to be found in authors list

Tags: publications, research-process, ethics, authorship

Last year I worked in a research lab in the US. My PI was very abusive so I eventually left for another lab. This individual was always extremely vindictive but I didn't expect that he would use all my work (graphs, tables almost verbatim) without even mentioning my name in the authors list or acknowledgments. One month before I left the lab we had submitted this work in a conference, and I was listed as a SECOND author in the submitted article. I have multiple emails between me and the rest of the lab members where I regularly sent them my data for discussion, reviewing etc. Also I have an email from a former colleague in which she explicitly asks me for my data after I left the lab. I never sent the data to that person at that time because I didn't trust her and I was struggling with my health at that time. They could retrieve them however anyway from my abovementioned emails, common dropbox etc. A new researcher who came to the lab after me, just one month prior to the submission of the article to the journal, ( and had zero involvement in the project before) is listed in the authors list.
I am young and new to the whole word of research and academia. Also, I would like to mention that I worked for free in that lab. That professor had promised to help me with my career instead of paying me (I know, what a fool)and instead he used all my work without giving me credit.
I don't know how to go about it and if I actually have any chance of getting something out of it.
I would appreciate your advice.

Comment: Have you tried searching this forum? I believe your question has been asked and answered already.

Comment: Welcome! I'm sorry you are in such a dire and unpleasant situation. You may want to have a look at https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/13700/19627 and the linked  questions, that are probably a good place to start. Please, edit your question if you believe your situation is wildly different, or as some other specificity, from what's described in those posts.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Does publishing graphs and tables verbatim from my unpublished work constitute plagiarism?

Answer (score 2):

Creating the graphs and tables for a paper does not *necessarily* entitle you to authorship (https://publicationethics.org/files/Authorship_DiscussionDocument.pdf).  But creating those graphs and tables nearly always requires some other activity that does entitle you to authorship.  Your work should be acknowledged at a minimum.

If you are entitled to authorship based on the standards of your field, you may:

- Request that the professor ask the journal for a correction of the author list.
- If that fails, request that the journal retract the paper for plagiarism.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Two months earlier, when we submitted the article to the conference, I was apparently entitled to be second author. I ran the whole statistical analysis-based on which I created the graphs- and collected data as well. I know he is doing this as retaliation for leaving the lab , some of the people listed as authors did absolutely nothing.

Comment: What is the chance of a high profile journal retracting an article for authorship dispute?

Comment: @estranged If the journal thinks the author list is wrong and the authors do not agree to correct it, the journal will retract.